# How to convert the following source into the below target

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

```
Student Name    Subject Name        Marks
Sam             Maths                100
Tom             Maths                 80
Sam             Physical Science      80
John            Maths                 75
Sam             Life Science          70
John            Life Science         100
John            Physical Science      85
Tom             Life Science         100
Tom             Physical Science      85
```

We want to load our Target Table as:

```
Student Name    Maths   Life Science    Physical Science
Sam              100      70              80
John              75     100              85
Tom               80     100              85
```

Comment: Google:  "oracle pivot"

Comment: Can the same student have two or three or more marks for the same subject? (Can they retake the exam, or the entire class, if they think they can do better - or if they fail the class the first time?) If so, do you need the highest mark, or the most recent mark, or the average, or what else? Also: if what you are showing here is the result of pre-processing you have already done (perhaps to handle exactly those situations!) then you should "pivot" at the same time (or instead of) what you already did; don't do the pre-processing and only then the pivoting, since both can be done in one pass.

Answer (score 0):

Try This.

```
SELECT student_name,
       "Maths",
       "Life Science",
       "Physical Science"
FROM
  (SELECT s.*
   FROM Student s ) 
PIVOT (MAX(Marks)
           FOR subject_name IN 
('Maths' AS "Maths",'Life Science' AS "Life Science",'Physical Science' AS "Physical Science") )
ORDER BY 3;
```

Comment: ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended

Comment: Thanks Kaushik Nayak but got below erreo